# Java Regex To Remove Middle of String

Tags: java, regex

I have looked at several regex questions on the site but none work, sorry if people feel this repititon.
I have this string in an XML file:

```
<MessageRef>Trading01</MessageRef>
```

Where `Trading01` will be a different String (which needs to be manually input) every time the xml is generated. The objective is to automatically generate any unique value here for testing purposes. How do I remove whatever is between `<MessageRef>` and `</MessageRef>`?

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
 message.replaceAll("(<MessageRef>)[^&]*(</MessageRef>)", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

It's a simple issue I know but it has been annoying me all morning! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it modified whatever is inside the XML tag:

```
message.replaceAll("(<MessageRef>)[^&]*(</MessageRef>)", "<MessageRef>" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "</MessageRef>");
```

Output:

```
<MessageRef>1435744441381</MessageRef>
```

Comment: not working for `<MessageRef>Trading01</MessageRef><MessageRef>Trading01</MessageRef><MessageRef>Trading01</MessageRef>`

Comment: Change the regex by [A-Za-z0-9]* for example. You can also look for anything but < (i.e. [^<]* )

Answer (score 2):

[Regex is not best tool to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg). Use parser instead. I like to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for its simplicity (its main purpose was to be HTML parser so it supports CSS queries).

Here is code example

```
String text = "<MessageRef>Trading01</MessageRef>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text, "", Parser.xmlParser());
System.out.println(doc);
System.out.println("---------");

Elements elements = doc.select("MessageRef");// cssQuery
for (Element el : elements) {//for each tag named MessageRef
    //set its text value to:
    el.text("date = " + new Date());
}

String replaced = doc.toString();
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output:

```
<messageref>
 Trading01
</messageref>
---------
<messageref>
 now = Wed Jul 01 12:03:52 CEST 2015
</messageref>
```

---

If you want to prevent prettifying your text to match XML standards like adding new lines simply use

```
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
```

and you will get

```
<messageref>Trading01</messageref>
---------
<messageref>date = Wed Jul 01 12:07:42 CEST 2015</messageref>
```

Comment: Really cool alternative, was unaware of Jsoup, I will definitely try this out too. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Reginald You don't have to use Jsoup. Java have its own build-in XML parser (which you probably should start with to really appreciate simplicity of Jsoup :).

Comment: Thank you for the advice Pshemo! Will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way as well:

Regex: `<MessageRef>(.*?)</MessageRef>`

Example:

```
System.out.println(message.replaceAll("<MessageRef>(.*?)</MessageRef>", "<MessageRef>" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + "</MessageRef>")));
```

Comment: There is noting like var in java

Comment: OP wanted `java` not `javascript` :)

Answer (score 0):

The following can also be done

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                    String input="<MessageRef>Trading01</MessageRef>";
                    System.out.println(input.substring(0,input.indexOf(">", 0)+1)+System.currentTimeMillis()+input.substring(input.indexOf("<",1),input.length()));

                }
```